# What is the meaning of "Betraying the slightest suggestion of a smile"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

What is the meaning of "Betraying the slightest suggestion of a smile" in this paragraph:

> Rostov asks, “What is the meaning of this, Captain?”

> The captain, who seemed mildly surprised by the question, had the good training to maintain the evenness of his affect.

> “I am here to show you to your quarters.”

> “These are my quarters.”

> **Betraying the slightest suggestion of a smile**, the captain replied, “No longer, I’m afraid.”

The above paragraph is from the novel named *A Gentleman in Moscow* by *Amor Towles*.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, please take a tour and frame your question in a better way. This one as it is is not a good question by ELL standard. Please improve it. Well, you can include where did you find it - the source, author, context etc. Or if you wrote it yourself? Things like that.

Answer (score 1):

> betraying the slightest suggestion of a smile.

That means simply that the captain was smiling very slightly, probably without intending to. It shows that he thinks Rostov is naive to believe that these are his quarters.

[Merriam-Webster "betray"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/betray)
4a : to reveal unintentionally
*betray one's true feelings*

A *suggestion* here is an indication or appearance.
The word *slightest* means that it is a very small indication, so it's a very small smile.

The OP has a quotation from "A Gentleman in Moscow" by Amor Towles.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please tell that what is the meaning of "slightest suggestion" here?

Comment: I added a clarification.